# CKEDITOR - Toolbar button with text

Tags: button, text, plugins, ckeditor, toolbar

I have a plugin to save the editor contents via Ajax. Right now the button on the toolbar has an image. I wanted to change that to have bold text spelling out 'SAVE'. Is this possible?

This is button currently in my plugin.

```
    editor.ui.addButton('ajax-save', {
      label: I18n.t('js.save'),
      command: ajax-save,
      className : 'cke_ajax_save'
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.cke_button__[[lowercased button name]]_label {
    display: inline !important
}
```

For example, CKEditor by default contains the following rule to show text in the `Source` button:

```
.cke_button__source_label {
    display: inline
}
```

(Note: there is no `important` flag in the editors styles, because this style is set after the default `display: none` rule. In your case I recommend using the `important` flag for simplicity.)

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you :)

Comment: This is not working for me even after careful cache clearing. When I delete the "icon" property in plugin.js, I see a blank button. My button, action, folder and icon are all called "sdp". In plugins/sdp/styles/sdp.css I have ".cke_button__sdp_label { display: inline !important; }" and plugin.js has the reference to the stylesheet: "editor.addContentsCss(pluginDirectory + 'styles/sdp.css');". What else am I missing?

Comment: Editor.addContentsCss adds a style sheet for the contents of the editor, not the UI. You need to load that style sheet manually on the page where you include ckeditor.js.

Comment: If you don't like css rules using `!important`, simply add `.cke_button_label` in front of your class, e.g. `.cke_button_label.cke_button__source_label`.